# Font awesome using font face

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-awesome

I'm looking for something like this

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style : normal;
         src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
         src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
               url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
               url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
               url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
               url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}

.myClass:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f024";
}
```

```html
<a class="myClass" href="#">This is a link</a>
```

I want to load font file using CSS property. And to create a custom class for font icon. The above didn't work. It failed to load respective icon. Instead it show bar

Comment: Seems to work here... Are you expecting a flag?

Comment: However, if I switch to HTTPS on StackOverflow, it does not work. This is because if you're connecting via HTTPS it will refuse to load resources from any other site that are only HTTP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try opening the Javascript console and adding the error messages that appear there to your question.

[When I tried your code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4w2uc61/), all it needed was for the maxcdn links to be SSL-based HTTP**S** links as opposed to insecure HTTP links.

That may be the solution to your issue, but it's hard to tell without the console error output.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
font-weight: normal;
font-style : normal;
       src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
       src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}

.myClass:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f024";
}
```

Comment: Or use protocol relative URLs like `url("//maxcdn...` https://jsfiddle.net/c4w2uc61/1/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Is there any argument to *not* using HTTPS though?

Comment: Well, if you use protocol relative links, you can use the same code locally (where you might not have HTTPS working) as remotely.

Comment: It's important to know this feature, but don't use it willy nilly. If you expect the resource to be secure, insist on it in your code. https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Nice browser compatibility:

```@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}```

Answer (score 1):

use cdn link to create **`@font-face`** as following way

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
    font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

Comment: Probably just woff2 format is still too risky for some sites.

Keep in mind:

```@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("../whatever.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("../whatever.woff2") format("woff2"); /* Super Modern Browsers */
  src: url("../whatever.woff") format("woff"); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  src: url("../whatever.svg") format("svg"); /* Legacy iOS */
  src: url("../whatever.ttf") format("truetype"); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if are including `font-awesome.min.css` in your page (as explained in Font-awesome's [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/get-started/)) then it already includes the following `@font-face`, at the very beginning of the file, and you wouldn't need to add your own:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are looking for FontAwesome then you're probably looking for this-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="champion-fontawesome-css" href="wp-content/themes/bla/inc/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.7.3" type="text/css" media="all">
```

If you are looking to load a custom font of your own then try this-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FFDINRoundWebPro';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_0_0.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FFDINRoundWebPro';
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_1_0.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FFDINRoundWebPro';
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_2_0.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_2_0.woff') format('woff'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FFDINRoundWebPro';
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_3_0.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/3103D9_3_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_3_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_3_0.woff') format('woff'), url('assets/fonts/3103D9_3_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

As you can see, for each font-weight i create another @font-face with the same font-family name.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question which was why I downvoted.

Comment: It wasn't my question.